# Popen output width is truncated, instead of full output it is showing

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, popen, os.system

I'm trying to get the output (AppID) of command "powershell.exe get-StartApps", So I can use it for some other purpose of my code. But output width is truncated and because of this situation I cannot use full AppID and because of this remaining part of code is failing.

Below is part of my code:

```
import subprocess
sp1=subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', 'get-StartApps'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
key = sp1.stdout.read().decode()
print(key)
```

The width of above code output is truncated, snap of output is as below
[image: output]

Additionally for information I tried "sp1.stdout.read()" or sp1.communicate[0] even I tried os.system to run this command and I got same output. I also tried to manipulate bufffsize, shell (True/False) and universal_newlines and have same output

could someone please help me to get rid of it.

Comment: This is just how powershell presents output by default, as running `Get-StartApps` in powershell directly shows the same trimming. See also ["How to fix truncated PowerShell output, even when I've specified -width 300".](https://superuser.com/questions/1049531/how-to-fix-truncated-powershell-output-even-when-ive-specified-width-300)

Comment: `Get-StartApps | Format-List` might work better for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get-StartApps | Format-List works correctly for this

```
import subprocess
sp1=subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', 'Get-StartApps | Format- 
List'],stdout=subprocess. PIPE)
key = sp1.stdout.read().decode()
print(key)
```

[image]